# Lightbox2, trouble with horizontal photo and order to display photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I have a problem with the Lightbox2 made by Lokesh.
https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
I am v2.11.3 and the display of horizontal photo is on the top of the screen in mobiles devices. I have try different options but doesn't work.

Another problem es the order the photos are displaying by Lightbox, I am using Colcate for horizontal grid, so the image follow left to right order but the Lightbox show me the photos follow the vertical order top to bottom, I don't know how I can fix it.

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/73562012/108930646-68c95c00-769a-11eb-9c71-ec83b816f2da.png)

leave you part of my code,
the file lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js you que find in the lokesh's page

thanks!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
</head>


   <div class="container gallery">
    

  <div class="grid">
      <!-- current -->
      <div class="grid-col grid-col--1">
        
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col grid-col--2">
          
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col grid-col--3">
          
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col grid-col--4">
          
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col grid-col--5">
          
    </div>
     
  
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="images/urban//urban7-david-porter.jpg"
            data-lightbox="roadtrip"
            data-title="Urban - oil on canvas">
            <img src="images/urban/urban7-david-porter.jpg" alt="Urban, canvas on oil, David Porter" width="100%"> 
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="images/urban/urban00-david-porter.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"
          data-title="Urban - oil on canvas">
        <img src="images/urban/urban00-david-porter.jpg" alt="Urban, canvas on oil, David Porter" width="100%"> 
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="images/urban/urban10-david-porter.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"
        data-title="Urban - oil on canvas">
        <img src="images/urban/urban10-david-porter.jpg" alt="Urban, canvas on oil, David Porter" width="100%"> 
        </a>
      </div>

</div>
</div>
  
<!-- colcate- grid -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/colcade@0/colcade.js"></script>

<script>
  var colc = new Colcade( '.grid', {
columns: '.grid-col',
items: '.grid-item'
});
</script>

<!-- lightbox -->
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script>
    lightbox.option({
    resizeDuration: 200,
    wrapAround: true,
    fadeDuration: 2000,
    fitImagesInViewport: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    });
</script>
```

my css

```
body.lb-disable-scrolling {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  outline: none;
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: none;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* Image border */
  border: 4px solid white;
  
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;

  /* Background color behind image.
     This is visible during transitions. */
  background-color: white;
}

.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url(../images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #EDE7E5;
}

.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight:;
  line-height: 1em;
  
}

.lb-data .lb-caption a {
  color: #424242;
}

.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C7C2C0;
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../images/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```